# android invoking activity from a multi-column listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-cursoradapter, multiple-columns

Within my project I have an activity with a multi-column ListView. This ListView draws its data from a custom CursorAdapter that I've implemented in a separate java module. I have listeners on a couple of the views within the ListView's rows, and these are implemented within the CursorAdapter. One of the listeners needs to edit the view content that called it and save the data back to the underlying database. This editing needs to startActivityForResult (as a custom dialog). However I get an error as an activity can only be invoked from another activity. I have tried moving the startActivityForResult to a procedure in the parent activity, but this has then to be a static procedure to be called from the listener and I get an error as startActivityForResult can't be in a static process. The error is 
"The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Has anyone a process for invoking an activity from a view listener where the view is a row element of a ListView?

The code below is the process I'm using in my CursorAdapter.

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

protected static class RowViewHolder {
    public Button btnLap;
    public TextView tvTime;
}

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

    RowViewHolder holder = new RowViewHolder();
    holder.btnLap = (Button) retView.findViewById(R.id.btn_lap);
    holder.tvTime = (TextView) retView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
    holder.btnLap.setOnClickListener(btnLapOnClickListener);
    holder.tvTime.setOnClickListener(tvTimeOnClickListener);

    retView.setTag(holder);

    return retView;
}

...

private OnClickListener tvTimeOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        String strTime = tv.getText().toString();
        Intent intentTimeEdit = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TimeEditDialog.class);
        intentTimeEdit.putExtra("Time", strTime);
        startActivityForResult(intentTimeEdit, EDIT_TIME_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
};
```

As per comment below, the code for the OnClickListener has been corrected to:

```
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        String strTime = tv.getText().toString();
        RowViewHolder holder = new RowViewHolder();
        holder = (RowViewHolder) ((View) v.getParent()).getTag();
        Intent intentTimeEdit = new Intent(holder.ctx, TimeEditDialog.class);
        intentTimeEdit.putExtra("Time", strTime);
        ((Activity)holder.ctx).startActivityForResult(intentTimeEdit, EDIT_TIME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}` its becomes clear that startActivityForResult or startActivity can be called only if class extends Acitvity.. It won't even accept inside inner class...

try

`((Activity)getBaseContext()).startActivityForResult(intentTimeEdit, EDIT_TIME_REQUEST_CODE);` and check the result.

Comment: Many thanks, CRUSADER, that resolves the problem. For anyone else with the same issue, note that the two getBaseContext() are invalid and I had to use the ctx context from RowViewHolder. I'll post the amended code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a context in the constructor of the adapter class, and then instead of

```
startActivityForResult(intentTimeEdit, EDIT_TIME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

do

```
ctx.startActivityForResult(intentTimeEdit, EDIT_TIME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Hi Israel, I tried your solution but got a compile error "The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Context". As per CRUSADER's solution, it looks like it needs to be cast to an activity.

Comment: oh sorry, you also need to cast the ctx to Activity in order you use the method startActivityForResult, due to the fact that it's a method of the Activity class.

should be :

    public CustomAdapter (Context context) implements BaseAdapter
    {
          this.ctx = context;
    }

    in the getView method

    ((Activity)ctx).startActivityForResult(..)